I get this error regarding the constructor when I try to compile with g++ and I'm using macOS :no matching constructor for initialization of
I have a perfectly normal code (a cpp and a cpp file) and a makefile and but when I try to compile it with g++ I get this :
g++ -std=c++11 -c subject.cpp -o subject.o
In file included from subject.cpp:1:
In file included from ./subject.hpp:1:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:848:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:165:28: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Subject'
        ::new ((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                           ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:290:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator<Subject>::construct<Subject, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::vector<std::string> &>' requested here
        __a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
            ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:808:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Subject>>::construct<Subject, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::vector<std::string> &, void>' requested here
    __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_address(__tx.__pos_),
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/vector:1597:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Subject>::__construct_one_at_end<std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::vector<std::string> &>' requested here
        __construct_one_at_end(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
        ^
subject.cpp:50:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::vector<Subject>::emplace_back<std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::string &, std::vector<std::string> &>' requested here
            subjects.emplace_back(s_id, s_name,s_credit,s_prerequisite,majors);
                     ^
subject.cpp:3:10: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<std::string>' to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>') for 5th argument
Subject::Subject(string subject_id_,string subject_name_,string credit_,string prerequisite_,string qualified_majors_id_)
         ^
./subject.hpp:9:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 5 were provided
class Subject{
      ^
./subject.hpp:9:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 5 were provided
1 error generated.
make: *** [subject.o] Error 1

and I can't understand what the problem is
these are the other files in case there is problem with them:
cpp:
#include "subject.hpp"

Subject::Subject(string subject_id_,string subject_name_,string credit_,string prerequisite_,string qualified_majors_id_)
{
subject_id=subject_id_;
subject_name=subject_name_;
credit=credit_;
prerequisite=prerequisite_;
qualified_majors_id=qualified_majors_id_;
}

string Subject::get_subject_id(){return subject_id;}
string Subject::get_subject_name(){return subject_name;}
string Subject::get_credit(){return credit;}
string Subject::get_prerequisite(){return prerequisite;}
string Subject::get_qualified_majors_id(){return qualified_majors_id;}

vector<Subject> readSubjectFromCSV(string &filename)
{
    vector<Subject> subjects;

    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << endl;
        return subjects;
    }

    string header;
    getline(file, header);

    string line;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string s_id, s_name, s_credit, s_prerequisite, s_qualified_majors_id;

        if (getline(iss, s_id, ',') &&
            getline(iss, s_name, ',') &&
            getline(iss, s_credit, ',') &&
            getline(iss, s_prerequisite, ',')) {
         
            vector<string> majors;
        
            while (getline(iss, s_qualified_majors_id, ';')) {
                majors.push_back(s_qualified_majors_id);
            }
            

        {
            subjects.emplace_back(s_id, s_name,s_credit,s_prerequisite,majors);
        }
            }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Error parsing line: " << line << endl;
        }
    }
    

    file.close();

    return subjects;
}

just before I added the new cpp and cpp file the previous files and the main.cpp worked just fine but when I added this part to the code no matter what I do I get this error

subjects.emplace_back(s_id, s_name, s_credit, s_prerequisite, majors);: majors is of type std::vector<std::string> but the last parameter of the Subject constructor is of type std::string.

OT: Please read What's the problem with "using namespace std;"? And note that doing it in a header file is even worse.

Also note: you are on MacOS (you should make this clear in your question) which means even though you invoked g++, you actually ran clang so you should change the tags to clang or clang++.  This issue is not related to GCC/G++.  It's also not related to make, so the makefile tag is not relevant.

Stack Overflow Usage note: A title should be an executive summary of the technical problem you are facing.  It should give a future asker who finds the question in a search results list and can only see the title some hint that the question is worth their time to read or not for help. The current title is so broad that it is nearly useless. It could apply to almost C++ problem.

Your Subject constructor takes five strings
 Subject(string subject_id_,string subject_name_,string credit_,string prerequisite_,string qualified_majors_id_);

but when you use your Subject constructor you pass four strings and a vector of strings
subjects.emplace_back(s_id, s_name,s_credit,s_prerequisite,majors);

Variable majors is a vector<string>.
You need to decide whether the fifth parameter of your Subject constructor should be a string or a vector<string>. Then change the code so that the constructor and the call to emplace_back match up.
